# Formatting list labels in Microsoft PowerPoint independently of the text that follows

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, text-formatting, numbering

I would like to format list labels without having the text right after the label affect that format. For example:

**1. First item**
**2.** Second item

The bolding of "1." is determined by the bolding of the F in First. But I cannot figure out how to do the precise formatting in <strike>Office</strike> PowerPoint 2016. I looked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/231473/how-can-i-stop-pages-from-bolding-italicizing-ordered-list-item-numbers-letters?newreg=fc15324397aa41b0bd0dac7540dd50cf) for a solution, but it appears that the solutions given are for earlier versions of office. How exactly do I get my list formatted like the one above?

Important edit: This concerns PowerPoint specifically, not Office in general.

Comment: Which Office application are you using?

Comment: Powerpoint. For some reason this is not a problem in Word.

Comment: Are you saying the numbering is being formatted like the text and you want to change it to be like your example, or the example indicates the problem and you want to change it so that the number format matches the text?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I typed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8203</kbd> at the beginning of the line
to insert a zero-width joiner. 
(Press *and hold* <kbd>Alt</kbd>
while typing <kbd>8</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>
***on the numeric keypad***; then release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.) 
That fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that Alt+(nnnn) works in Microsoft Office. I probably knew it once, but somehow I had forgotten.

Comment: But decimal 8203 equals **200B** in hexadecimal,  so I believe that you are getting code point U+200B, Zero Width Space.

Answer (score 1):

**Asker Clarified They Only Meant PowerPoint 2016**
So I tried it out and I had the same results as you. It appears this isn't a new thing as I was able to find a [Microsoft question on the same topic.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/unbold-numbering-list/1fb8c7dd-210e-48bb-bc0d-973da49eadd1)

I'm utterly horrified this is the best workaround that I can come up with... but it will do the job. Re-posting "solution":

> Select the "T" and press Ctrl+B to UNbold it (along with the number.)
>
> Put the text cursor just to the left of the T then choose Insert > Symbols Symbol from the ribbon.
> In the Symbol dialog box, choose Font:  (normal text)
> Make sure that from: Unicode (hex) is selected
> In the Character code: box, type:  034f
>
> Verify that that selects the character named:  Combining Grapheme Joiner
> Click Insert
> You can now  select just the T and bold it again.  The character you just inserted  has no width, but fools PPT into thinking that there's an unbolded  character before the T.

So in your case, you can do the following to replicate what you want:

1. Create your list as:
   **1. First**
   **2. S**econd
2. Insert the Character above in front of both bolded characters ^ representing my invisible no width character
   **1. ^F**irst
   **2. ^S**econd
3. Unbold the S in Second and you will be done.
   **1. ^F**irst
   **2. ^**Second

My screenshot from PowerPoint:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: The problem is in PowerPoint, not Office in general. I should have made that clear.

Comment: Updated based on just PowerPoint. Not proud of this workaround... but it works

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Word, the formatting of the number or bullet before a list item
is determined by the formatting of the paragraph mark
at the end of the paragraph. 
This is easy to see (and manipulate) if you click on “Show/Hide ¶”:

[image: numbered list in Microsoft Word, with formatted numbers]

but you can select the paragraph marks even if you can’t see them. 
And, of course, the paragraph marks are invisible in printout,
so the fact that they’re formatted
won’t directly affect the appearance of the document.

Oddly, I couldn’t get it to work for underlining.

Comment: The problem is in PowerPoint, not Office in general. I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as [Will.Beninger’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1214467/150988#1214473),
which, in turn, is based on the [“Unbold numbering list” page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/unbold-numbering-list/1fb8c7dd-210e-48bb-bc0d-973da49eadd1)
at [Microsoft Community (answers.microsoft.com)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us),
but this one is somewhat simplified and illustrated better.

1. Type your list. 
   (Format it as a numbered list.) 
   Select the entire first paragraph and bold it:

   [image: second item is not bold]
2. Click at the beginning of the **s**econd item/paragraph;
   i.e., the one where you want to format the number
   without (visibly) formatting the text. 
   In the Ribbon, go to the “Insert” tab, “Symbols” pane,
   and click on “Symbol” (the one with the **Ω** icon). 
   Ensure that “Unicode (hex)” is selected in the “from” field
   (bottom right corner of the window),
   and type “200D” into the “Character code” field. 
   The words “Zero Width Joiner” should appear under “Unicode name”
   (bottom left corner of the window).

   [image: “Insert Symbol” dialog box]

   Click on “Insert” and “Close”.
3. Your slide still looks the same as it did before,
   but there is now an invisible (zero-width) character
   to the left of the insertion point (i.e., to the left of the “S”)<sup>1</sup>. 
   The next step is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**←** (cursor left)</kbd>
   (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>) to select it. 
   The insertion point (cursor) will disappear.
4. Now that you have the invisible character
   at the beginning of the list item selected,
   format it as you wish. 
   The number “2” will be formatted the same.

   [image: number “2” is bold]

   (There’s really no need to embolden the “S”,
   just to unbold it in the next step.)

Since you’re formatting the *number* “2” the same as
the (entire) first list item, once you understand this technique,
you can do it a little more efficiently:

1. Type your list. 
   (Format it as a numbered list.)
2. Click at the beginning of the **s**econd item/paragraph
   and insert the “Zero Width Joiner” character, as described above.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**←** (cursor left)</kbd>
   (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>) to select it the invisible character. 
   Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**↑** (cursor up)</kbd>
   to additionally select the (entire) first list item.
4. Format the selected text (*including* the invisible character) as you wish.

[The above was tested on PowerPoint 2013.]

It seems to me that the Unicode characters 200B (“Zero Width Space”)
and 200C (“Zero Width Non-Joiner”) work as well as the 200D. 
And, as far as I know, 034f (“Combining Grapheme Joiner”),
the one [suggested by Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/unbold-numbering-list/1fb8c7dd-210e-48bb-bc0d-973da49eadd1), works also.
__________
<sup>1</sup> You can “see” that it is there
by the way <kbd>**←** (cursor left)</kbd>
and <kbd>**→** (cursor right)</kbd> behave. 
For example, if you click at the end of the first list item
and press <kbd>**→**</kbd>,
the insertion point will move to the beginning of the second list item. 
But if you press <kbd>**→**</kbd> again,
the insertion point will (apparently) stay still. 
It has actually moved to the right of the invisible character,
but it’s still to the left of the “S”.

Comment: That zero-width joiner didn't appear in the symbols window, but Alt-8203 brought it up anyway and fixed the problem.

Comment: (1) What do you mean, “didn't appear in the symbols window”? As you can see from the screenshot in my answer, none of the invisible characters ***appear*** in the symbols window. (2) Are you sure? Decimal 8203 equals **200B** in hexadecimal, so I believe that you are getting code point U+200B, Zero Width Space.

Answer (score 0):

(This a usage suggestion, not an answer.)

1. Insert a slide at the start of your presentation. Set its slide number to 0 so it doesn't mess up your displayed slide count. (**Design** ribbon > **Slide Size** > **Custom Slide Size** > **Number slides from**.) Use it to leave documentation on the technical construction of the slide deck and instructions to future users/editors. (Yes, that means you too!)
2. Colour it really obnoxiously and set the slide to hidden so it won't present by mistake. (Mine is red text on yellow background.)

This kind of trickery, while it does work, is a kludge. (An honourable kludge, but a kludge nonetheless.) By definition it's a non-standard workaround. Even experienced PowerPoint designers won't see this shim, and may not recognize what is going on. Someone will always think something is broken, and in "helping," destroy your workaround, and never fix it.

I use zero-width joiners and other invisible characters often. (They all serve different purposes, so choose wisely!) As identified by others in this post, they're easy to detect in Word, but PowerPoint's designers decided against a reveal formatting option. The notes pane supports limited rich text, but makes it effectively impossible for users to understand what's going on in Normal view. Better editing tools, like indent ruler control, are available in Notes view. (Yes, that's how you deal with those infernal indents that came from pasted text.) But they're insufficient.

Hope this helps future you!

Signed,
Past Me